# how to customise angular2 textmask

Tags: angular

I am new in angular2. I want phone number text mask. according to this

```
pattern= (?:(?=^91)[0-9]{12}|(?!^91)[0-9]{10,15})$
```

How do I customize it in this pattern format?

Comment: you want to use this pattern in your Mobile field right ? if so whats the error you are facing ?

Comment: Please edit your question and add some details in which way you have to adapt the mask. What is not working?

Comment: @ventiseis-  
i have a text field for phone number.if the phone number in indian country code ,it will allow only 10digit after country code. other wise any 10 to 15 digit.how can i modify this code ->public mask = ['(', /[1-9]/, /\d/, /\d/, ')', ' ', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '-', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/] itget from net it work fine

Answer (score 0):

As per your question if you want to use this regx than simply add this as pattern in your model driven form as validation.

else if you are using [Primeng Mask](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/inputmask) you can simply add your required pattern as `mask` attribute there. like this

```
<p-inputMask [(ngModel)]="val" mask="a*-999-a999"></p-inputMask>
```

Comment: i have a text field for phone number.if the phone number in indian country code ,it will allow only  10digit after country code. other wise any 10 to 15 digit. how it possible it with angular2 textmask.is there condition check is possible?

Comment: have you checked primeng's Mask ? also for customize you need to know country code before after that you can add dynamic validations on the basis of that country code.

Comment: it is not suitable